# Scope of #define in a single main file

Tags: c, scope, macros, c-preprocessor

I know that probably there is no concept of scope for macros, but please help me understand the following output - which seems to suggest that macros are local to functions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define A 100
void fun();
int main()
{

    fun();
    printf("%d\n",A);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void fun()
{
    #undef A

}
```

The output of the program is 100 though according to me it should have been a compiler error. Please explain why?

Comment: You can't run preprocessor commands in functions. They're removed from compiled code. That's why they're called preprocessor: they are executed and removed before the program is compiled. In fun(), you are undefining the number 100.

Comment: @user1131435: Why did you not post it as an answer? I see it was posted way before other answers.Post it as an answer and i will upvote it.

Comment: Actually @user1131435 comment is not quite right. You can put pre-processor directives in functions and they will affect the text in the usual ways, they just don't "run" in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre-processor works on the *text of your source code* and it does it *before the compiler proper ever starts to run*.

In essence your compiler works on a file that looks like

```
/* Lots of code from the included files omitted */
void fun();
int main()
{

    fun();
    printf("%d\n",100);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void fun()
{

}
```

So running and printing 100 is exactly what you would expect.

Notice that all the pre-processor directives are gone, and that all instances of `A` between the `define` and the `undef` have been replaced with `100`.

The thing to remember is:

- The pre-processor runs, changing the *text*
- Then the compiler runs on the result

Comment: so the preprocessor does not traverse the program in the logical sequence,but from top to bottom, right?

Comment: Er...the logical order for the pre-processor *is* top to bottom. The pre-processor is a completely different step from compiling. Yes, the compiler runs if transparently, but it is often implemented in a separate program (`cpp`) and you can use it on non-source text files if you want (most people prefer `m4`).

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor makes a single pass though the program text at compile time. By the time the program runs all of the directives are long gone.

Originally, the preprocessor was actually a separate program that understood C only to the extent that it parsed tokens the same way. After creating a macro-expanded version of the program as a temporary file, the real compiler was run. Today, it's integrated into the compiler, but in such a way that the effect is the same.

This is how the convention of using all-upper-case macro names began, i.e., in order to emphasize their substantially different nature. You can still get the compiler to output the expanded-but-uncompiled intermediate text. This is occasionally useful when tracking down bugs and understanding complicated conditional compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run preprocessor commands in functions. They're removed from compiled code. That's why they're called preprocessor: they are executed and removed before the program is compiled. In fun(), you are undefining the number 100.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are executed at compile time (in fact before the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

macro expansion is done at preprocessing step, which is a step before compiling.
If you like to see how the code looks after this step, try compile with preprocessing only option.

e.g.

```
gcc -E myfile.c > myfile.ppout
```

and read the output.